# How to get some components in recycelrview adapter from main layout?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview in activity_main.xml and I have there the image which shows to user - empty or not empty recyclerview. activity_main.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/main_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:id="@+id/main_recycler_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scrollbars="vertical" />

      <LinearLayout
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:id="@+id/block_no_alarms"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <ImageView
             android:src="@drawable/ic_nothing"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="70dp" />
         <TextView
             android:text="@string/no_alarms"
             android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And I have recyclerview one item xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
     app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorDark"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_time_alarm_one_item"
         android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:textSize="25sp"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_description_alarm_one_item"
         android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_time_alarm_one_item"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:maxLines="2"
         android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_time_alarm_one_item"
         android:layout_marginEnd="60dp" />
       <Switch
          android:id="@+id/s_switch_alarm_one_item"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:checked="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_margin="15dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
       </RelativeLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And I wanna during long press click to this cardview to delete one item from the recyclerview. Adapter:

```
public class AlarmsAdapterMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsAdapterMain.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> listTimes = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> listDescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Boolean> listStarted = new ArrayList<>(); // checked a switch

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alarm_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.time.setText(listTimes.get(i));
    viewHolder.description.setText(listDescriptions.get(i));
    viewHolder.aSwitch.setChecked(listStarted.get(i));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listTimes.size();
}

public void deleteAll() {
    listDescriptions.clear();
    listTimes.clear();
    listStarted.clear();
}

public void add(String time, String description) {
    listTimes.add(time);
    listDescriptions.add(description);
    listStarted.add(true); // by default
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView time, description;
    private Switch aSwitch;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_alarm_one_item);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description_alarm_one_item);
        aSwitch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_switch_alarm_one_item);
       // I try to set long listener here
    }
}
```

}

I've done it, but I need to show or hide image or recyclerview if it need. For example, I have one alarm, user deletes it alarm and he sees empty layout but he must see image(LinearLayout) and hide recyclerview. So, how can I do it inside my adapter?

Answer (score 0):

control your arrayLists from outside of your adapter, for example in your activity you should have a list of your data and pass the arrayList to your adapter's constructor, and manipulate your adapter data from activity and just notifyDataChange after any changes on your arrayList. so when you delete data or add some data, you can check your arrayList size in last line of your ad or delete operations (in your activity), and if arrayList size equals to 0 you should do changes on your UI.

also there is another way, you can have an interface that implements in your activity and it should have two methods for zeroMode or nonZeroMode and you can pass this interface to your adapter and invoke these methods when your arrayList size become zero or non-zero in your adapter.

Comment: I know, but how can I call these methods from activity in adapter?

Comment: I have in main activity the next code
`  private void checkForEmptyAlarms() {
        if (alarmsAdapterMain.getItemCount() > 0) {
            recyclerViewMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyAlarmsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            recyclerViewMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyAlarmsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }`
And how can I call its inside my adapter? 
I'm trying to call intent to restart activity 'cause onResume() calls checkFor...() and it works but maybe it is not clear code, isn't it?

Comment: As I said if you want to call a method of your activity in your adapter you should use an interface(second approach that I said in answer).

Comment: I have to call the method from activity..ok, But how can I realisez it in my adapter? The content of that method was written in my last comment.